# texmaker 5.0.4 you do not have permission to access this file when using different sections as .tex files

Tags: errors, texmaker

I am using texmaker to edit a latex document and instead of writing the text after each \section{title}...., I simply want to separate the sections in different individuals .tex files just like you would write a book with multiple chapters and then call them as \input{sections/6-conclusion} for example.

I can compile without problems, all good but when I try to ctrl+click in the embedded pdf visualizer of the texmaker in order to redirect me directly into various sections to edit the latex text directly there, I get the error "you do not have permission to read this folder".

I have already have full access to everyone who uses my computer to that folder/subfolders so this is not a problem, but rather I believe is a texmaker error of jumping directly into separate .tex mini-files which represent various sections/chapter of a global .tex file.

I have just updated texmaker to the last version 5.0.4 so I don't think is due to the old texmaker version but rather some bug of visualization/ redirection towards the original .tex file.

Anyone had similar problems?

How to solve this? Is a bit annoying.

Thanks,S.M.

Comment: Try to reinstall version 5.0.3 and see if the problem disappears. Eventually, you can download the portable version of 5.0.3, which may be run without affecting you previous installation. If you are on windows, it can be connected to your rights when you installed version 5.0.3. If you installed with administrative right, you may need to upgrade from the same account. Or it may be a bug in the new version.

Comment: You may also try to run the portable version of 5.0.4 to see if the problem still exist.